# How to get channel icon by channelId with enpoint search from YouTube Data API V3

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube, youtube-api

I make a request on /search enpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC8M5YVWQan_3Elm-URehz9w&key=AIzaSyAp8yGkCqT9e9p7IzgpE24KGoqLRgNhOg0&q=Utopia

I receive videos and their previews, but the channel icon is not coming, and I read how you can get the channel icon, there I understood, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list what you need to get channelId from the Id class and pass its to channelId query parameter, after which data about the channel will come to the Snippet model, and the icon to Thumbnails, but I don't understand how and where to get the channelId from the model Id and where it is passed to the request parameter, where it is better to get it his ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By *channel icon*, you mean the channel profile picture? - if so, then, yes, the *channel icon* appears in the `youtube#channel` of the response.

This is part of the response you receive by using [your sample request](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UC8M5YVWQan_3Elm-URehz9w&key=AIzaSyAp8yGkCqT9e9p7IzgpE24KGoqLRgNhOg0&q=Utopia):

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "hwZ_cPPePXCDt8h44C-3Ym9NP2I",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "regionCode": "CO",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 244,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "p0M_r8_zUEtBcT7MrX49-24RkXU",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#channel",
        "channelId": "UC8M5YVWQan_3Elm-URehz9w"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2015-04-14T02:57:14Z",
        "channelId": "UC8M5YVWQan_3Elm-URehz9w",
        "title": "Utopia Show",
        "description": "Клоунада и театральщина Реклама: utopia@tag.show #utopia_show #topatella #topsecret.",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLRf5WOTI2S1ruF-YWz22VFqh5QxpMEZiqWX5vDWTw=s88-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLRf5WOTI2S1ruF-YWz22VFqh5QxpMEZiqWX5vDWTw=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLRf5WOTI2S1ruF-YWz22VFqh5QxpMEZiqWX5vDWTw=s800-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo"
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Utopia Show",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2015-04-14T02:57:14Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "0JhSluN0BMHidIIoDBC19t7HNik",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "Ywpd8M6wfHc"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-10-05T13:43:17Z",
        "channelId": "UC8M5YVWQan_3Elm-URehz9w",
        "title": "ТЫ БЫ НИКОГДА ТАКОЕ НЕ ЗАГУГЛИЛ #9",
        "description": "https://go.skyeng.ru/utopia_show_skypro - Начни свой путь в IT с онлайн-университетом Skypro. Забирай 10% скидку на один из курсов по промокоду ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ywpd8M6wfHc/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ywpd8M6wfHc/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Ywpd8M6wfHc/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Utopia Show",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2021-10-05T13:43:17Z"
      }
    },
    [other videos items here]
  ]
}
```

You can get from this response the *channel icon* as follows:

```
JSON_response.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url
```

You will get:

> https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLRf5WOTI2S1ruF-YWz22VFqh5QxpMEZiqWX5vDWTw=s240-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo

Where `JSON_response` is the response of the request. I'm not sure how you're reading the items in the response, but, I hope this answer helps you.

Comment: I have already tried doing this, but the problem is that I need to display the channel icon under the video. when i do a search i am displayed 20 videos in recyclerview and under each of them there should be a channel owner icon. Sorry for not specifying

Comment: @TapchylovRadin then, for that you have to do a second request - this time, to the `channel` endpoint and sending the `channel_id` you get in each video; be sure not to make multiple requests to get the same channel icon. In the `search` response, it wont come the channel info, but the `channel_id` . which you can use for make a second request and get channel's details you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you gave a good idea!

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but how can I display two requests at once in one recyclerview, i.e. / search and / channel?

Comment: could you answer me?

Comment: @TapchylovRadin I have no idea about android or kotlin, sorry. Have you search anything?